# Pyform dynamic styling does not take an effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyforms

I started `pyforms` yesterday and it looks like many parts of the framework is not documented yet.

I write an application which requires a style change on demand. I insist on using `ControlButton.style` and not a `CSS` file. The [documentation](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/projects/Pyforms-WEB/en/v4/api-reference/python/controls.html#controlbase) does not provide how to use `style` property and my try failed. It does not make any effect.

[image: pyforms style image]

```
from pyforms.basewidget import BaseWidget
from pyforms.controls import ControlText
from pyforms.controls import ControlButton
import os


class GUI(BaseWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__('A test')

        self.set_margin(10)

        self._directory = ControlText('Directory')
        self._directory.value = 'C:\\'
        self._directory.changed_event = self.referesh_check
        self._ok  = ControlButton('OK')
        self._formset = [ ('_directory', ' ', '_ok') ]
        self.referesh_check()

    def referesh_check(self):
        dirpath = self._directory.value
        if os.path.exists(dirpath):
            print('found: ', dirpath)
            self._directory.style='color:green'
        else:
            print('not found: ', dirpath)
            self._directory.style='color:red'
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pyforms import start_app
    start_app(GUI)
```

---

*Note:*

Using style as method fails with an error

```
self._directory.style('background-color:green')
```

> AttributeError: 'ControlText' object has no attribute 'style'